# What is the command for a cronjob that will be run at 18:30 and 23:00 every weekday?

Tags: azure, cron

I need to create a cronjob, that will be executed on every week day on the following time: 18:30 and 23:00.

I am unsure how to combine this, into one cron:

30  18  *   *   1-5

The above will be executed at 18:30 every weekday, but how do I add the 23:00 in the same cron?

22:30 instead of 23:00 would also be O.K.

Comment: Does it have to be a single job? Simplest solution would be to specify 2 jobs. Probably more readable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about 2 lines in the cronlist?

```
30 18 * * 1-5
00 23 * * 1-5
```

Otherwise you can try multiple values (see more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161128152110/http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html)), but i think it is not possible to have on both 18:30 and 23:00.

```
30 18,22 * * 1-5
```

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'OrderStatusCustomerMail.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: The schedule expression '30 18 * * 1-5 00 23 * * 1-5' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string.


Not allowed. :/

Comment: I can only give one cron as an argument.

Comment: maybe you can try
    30 18,22 * * 1-5
it will fulfill "22:30 instead of 23:00 would also be O.K."

[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20161128152110/http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html)

Comment: Seems like it works, thank you.

[10/06/2019 19.54.16] The next 5 occurrences of the 'OrderStatusCustomerMail.OrderStatusCustomerMail.Run' schedule will be:
[10/06/2019 19.54.16] 10/06/2019 22.30.00
[10/06/2019 19.54.16] 11/06/2019 18.30.00
[10/06/2019 19.54.16] 11/06/2019 22.30.00
[10/06/2019 19.54.16] 12/06/2019 18.30.00
[10/06/2019 19.54.16] 12/06/2019 22.30.00